Implement TailwindCSS class from backend
I am trying to make a website builder where users can set colors based on their needs just by clicking the colors. The main problem, the color is not working. Here is the function
function generateTemplateClass($input)
{
    $class = [];
    $style = [];
    if ($input && count($input) > 0) {
        foreach ($input as $key => $item) {
            switch ($key) {
                case 'backgroundColor':
                    $style[] = "background-color: {$item}";
                    $class[] = "bg-[{$item}]";
                    break;
                case 'textColor':
                    $style[] = "color: {$item}";
                    $class[] = "text-[{$item}]";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    $result = [
        'class' => $class,
        'style' => $style,
    ];
    return $result;
}

Blade file:
<nav class="{{$class}} border-gray-200 fixed w-full block z-30 top-0 border-b" data-accordion="collapse">
.....
</nav>

Output:
<nav class="bg-[#010432] text-[#e6e5ff] border-gray-200 fixed w-full block z-30 top-0 border-b" data-accordion="collapse">
.....
</nav>

Right now, I am trying to achieve it with using styles but I want to use tailwind class which is easier. How do I generate class based on user color inputs. Thank you

This question is similar to: Trouble with Dynamic Color in Tailwind Component. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Its different actually, in this case. User can change theme whatever they want by clicking only. Backend store the class, then push it to blade files. For example: changing background color of div

As per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


You could consider using the style attribute:
<nav
  class="border-gray-200 fixed w-full block z-30 top-0 border-b"
  style="{{$style}}"
  data-accordion="collapse"
>
.....
</nav>


I have been using style for the project. I am trying to achieve it with tailwind. I got the solution but it takes a long time to build npm run build for every changes if user want to see the result
